# Grid Search Pool Classifiers for Dynamic Classifier Selection Ensembles

Tags: gridsearchcv

I would like to grid search pool classifiers hyper parameter of **OLA()** ( Overall Local Accuracy ) model from **deslib** python package.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification


from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


from deslib.dcs.ola import OLA


from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
```

Then :

```
X , y = make_classification( n_samples = 10000 , n_features = 20 , n_informative = 15 , n_redundant = 5 , random_state = 999 )

model = OLA()

cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold( n_splits = 10 , n_repeats = 3 , random_state = 999 )

grid = dict()

grid[ 'pool_classifiers' ] = [ [ LogisticRegression() , DecisionTreeClassifier() , GaussianNB() ] ,
                               [ LogisticRegression() , DecisionTreeClassifier() ] ]

search = GridSearchCV( model , grid , scoring = 'accuracy' , cv = cv )

search_results = search.fit( X , y )
```

But the following error message is raised :

```
NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

It means model in the pool must be fitted prior to grid searching but I thought fitting took place on each train fold of the cv step.

Does it mean I must fit myself each model on training folds ?

Thanks for helping on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this problem :

Let's say I have the classifiers pools I want to cross validate :

```
grid = dict()

grid[ 'pool_classifiers' ] = [ ( 'pool_01' , [ LogisticRegression() , DecisionTreeClassifier() , GaussianNB() ] ) , 
                               ( 'pool_02' , [ LogisticRegression() , DecisionTreeClassifier() ] ) ]
```

Then I can use the following function :

```
def ola_cv( X , y , cv ) :

  scores = dict()

  for pool_classifiers in grid[ 'pool_classifiers' ] :

      scores[ pool_classifiers[ 0 ] ] = list()

  for train_ix , test_ix in cv.split( X , y ) :

    X_train = X[ train_ix , : ]
    y_train = y[ train_ix ]

    X_test = X[ test_ix , : ]
    y_test = y[ test_ix ]

    for pool_classifiers in grid[ 'pool_classifiers' ] : 

      for model in pool_classifiers[ 1 ] :

        model.fit( X_train, y_train )

      ola = OLA( pool_classifiers = pool_classifiers[ 1 ] )

      ola.fit( X_train , y_train )

      y_pred = ola.predict( X_test )

      score = accuracy_score( y_test , y_pred )

      scores[ pool_classifiers[ 0 ] ].append( score )

  for k in scores.keys():

    print( f'pool_classifiers : {k} | accuracy : {np.mean(scores[ k ])} ({np.std(scores[ k ])})')

  return scores
```

to obtain for each classifiers pool mean accuracy ( and standard deviation ) on 10 * 3 = 30 folds.

NB : Mayne grid should be an argument of the ola_cv function.